# Loading module once, requirejs with examples

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I already ask similar question: [Requirejs, what it means "Requirejs loads each module once"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434356/requirejs-what-it-means-requirejs-loads-each-module-once) 
 
but in that topic no one answer the main question, because i asked in wrong way.

So i will provide some easy examples to show on what i mean:

**Module counter.js**

```
1:    define([], function() {
2:        console.log("Executing counter");
3:        var counter = 0;
4:   
5:        return {
6:            increment: function() { counter++; },
7:            get: function() { return counter; }
8:        };
9:    });
```

**Module test1.js**

```
1:    define(['counter'], function(counter) {
2:        console.log("Executing test1");
3:        counter.increment();
4:    });
```

**Module test2.js**

```
1:    define(['counter'], function(counter) {
2:        console.log("Executing test2");
3:        counter.increment();
4:    });
```

**Main.js**

```
1:    require(['test1', 'test2', 'counter'], function(test1, test2, counter) {
2:        console.log("Executing main");
3:        alert(counter.get());
4:    });
```

So module main.js is entry point of the application which will first load dependencies "test1", "test2" and "counter".
(Executing order: Executing counter, Executing test1, Executing test2, Executing main)

So if i understand sentence "Requirejs loads each module once" that means (for example of counter.js) code from line 1 to 9 will be executed
**ONLY ONCE** beside fact that test1, test2 and main module have counter in their dependencies list?
If that is correct, **test1 is "in charge" for executing counter module?**
And if that is correct, after executing counter, in memory will be **ONLY ONE** object which will be returned from counter?
When test2 load counter it will get that ONE object?
(**in another words test2 will not execute again code from counter neither main, they will use existing counter object**)?
**SO, am i creating SINGLETON here?**

In the end all of the modules can affect counter value (in beginning, counter = 0) through functions(increment, get) closures?
**Closures will be alive while counter object exist in memory?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed your `main.js` to log to the console

```
require(['test1', 'test2', 'counter'], function(test1, test2, counter) {
        console.log("Executing main");
        console.log(counter.get());
});
```

In addition I have an index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Counter Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Counter Demo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

After loading `index.html` and then opening the web console I have

```
[22:04:09.077] "Executing counter"
[22:04:09.077] "Executing test1"
[22:04:09.077] "Executing test2"
[22:04:09.077] "Executing main"
[22:04:09.078] 2
```

### Log messages

To make it more clear what happens I suggest to substitute the log messages

- `Executing counter` -> `Creating the counter AMD module`
- `Executing test1` -> `Incrementing the counter in module "test1"`
- `Executing test2` -> `Incrementing the counter in module "test2"`
- `"Executing main"` -> `Retrieving the counter value in module "main"`

The I get the following **result** in the console log

```
[22:16:46.368] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/css/main.css
[22:16:46.368] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/scripts/require.js
[22:16:46.369] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/scripts/main.js
[22:16:46.588] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/scripts/test1.js
[22:16:46.589] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/scripts/test2.js
[22:16:46.590] file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/requirejs-counter2/scripts/counter.js
[22:16:46.381] "Creating the counter AMD module"
[22:16:46.381] "Incrementing the counter in module "test1""
[22:16:46.381] "Incrementing the counter in module "test2""
[22:16:46.381] "Retrieving the counter value in module "main""
[22:16:46.381] 2
```

### Conclusion

The counter module is only loaded once and thus creating the counter object only once. You may consider it to be a `Singleton`.