# Does AMD format require that modules are singletons?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Is there anything in the AMD specification to say that require'd modules must be supplied with the same object? It seems to be fairly common practice to assume that a require'd module is a single instance supplied to all requiring modules, but is there anything to prevent a module loader treating loaded modules as merely cached (possibly reloading them at some point)?

For example (hypothetically speaking), would an AMD loader be guaranteed to distribute the same instance of a message bus module across various different dependent modules, so they could use it to send each other messages?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19083992/1630906

Comment: I'm asking about the specification - not about one particular implementation. There are other AMD loaders than require.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, modules should be singletons.

From the [spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md):

> **define() function**
>
> ...
>
> **factory**
>
> The third argument, factory, is a function that should be executed to instantiate the module or an object. If the factory is a function it should only be executed once. If the factory argument is an object, that object should be assigned as the exported value of the module.